# How to hide the console output while using robot.rebot command in Robot Framework?

Tags: python, console, robotframework

If am trying to combine some `output.xml` files in different directories
using the following 'robot.rebot' command:

`python -m robot.rebot --name Combined_Suite --logtitle Overall_Execution_Log....`

But whenever I run the command in Command Prompt (Windows), this message about the generated files is shown:

`Log:     F:\....\RF_Pilot\Result\Result_01_25_2020_23_22_16\log.html
 Report:  F:\....\RF_Pilot\Result\Result_01_25_2020_23_22_16\report.html`

How can I hide these lines in windows?

There is no `--console quiet`option for `rebot` as it is present for `robot` command.

Also, I tried `pythonw` instead of `python`. It hides the message but does not generate the combined output.

Answer (score 0):

It's a brute-force solution, but may serve your purposes - redirect the output (stdout and stderr) so it's not displayed :

```
python -m robot.rebot ... >nul 2>&1
```

`nul` is a reserved file name in windows, mapped to the NUL device (similar to Linux `/dev/null`); `2>&1` is redirecting stderr to stdout (again quite similar as in Linux).

Naturally, this will supress *all* output from the command execution.